# Firebase anonymous login issue

Tags: firebase

I am writing an android application and using firebase anonymous authentication for users. When the program is first installed on a device, i use anonymous login for that device to create a unique id, then i store it in the memory and then always use that unique id as a unique username for that device. Here is my code:

```
public String getUserId() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("USER_ID",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String id = prefs.getString("USER_ID", "NOT_FOUND");
    return id;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String userId = getUserId();
    if (userId.equals("NOT_FOUND")) {
        if (f == null) {
            f = new Firebase(
                    "https://marketlist.firebaseio.com/sharedlists");
        }

        try {
            Firebase ref = f.getParent();
            SimpleLogin authClient = new SimpleLogin(ref);

            authClient
                    .loginAnonymously(new SimpleLoginAuthenticatedHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void authenticated(Error error, User user) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                System.out.println("");
                            } else {
                                // We are now logged in
                                String id = user.getUid();
                                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                                        "USER_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                prefs.edit().putString("USER_ID", id)
                                        .commit();

                            }

                        }
                    });
            Firebase.goOffline();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Firebase.goOffline();
        }

    }
}
```

Here i am concerned about uniqueness of that id. Does firebase anonymous login give a unique id amongst the online anonymous users, or it gives the application-based unique id? Is there any chance that two devices may be given same id here? If there is a chance, where can i check whether that id exists? (I also store the given id in firebase repository, and i want to check whether that id was given before) .

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uids generated for anonymous auth. are very similar to [UUIDs (v4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), which use a combination of the current timestamp, and randomness, to come up with an id that is essentially unique. It is very, very, very unlikely that there will ever be another user with the same id, to the point where your application shouldn't even check.

If you really wanted to check, however, you could have your clients write to `/users/<uid>` using a Firebase transaction, and ensure that no other client has written to that location before.